# AttributeError at /pro/bill/8/pdf/ 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-views

i want to print the details from the data of a  model object in to pdf

i have googled a lot to make sure if someone has faced this issue earlier but  most of the answers i have found aren't a solution for my issue

**models.py**

```
class Direct(models.Model):
    type=models.CharField(max_length=128,null=True,blank=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    price=models.IntegerField()
    meters=models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,max_digits=5, 
    decimal_places=2)
    discount=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    phone_number=models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    type2=models.CharField(max_length=128,null=True,blank=True)
    meters2=models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,max_digits=5, 
    decimal_places=2)
    price2=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    discount2=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset=D.objects.all()
    # serializer=
    # order=D.objects.get(order_id)
    order = get_object_or_404(queryset, id=order_id)
    type=order.type
    price=order.price
    meters =order.meters
    price=price*meters
    discount=order.discount
    total=price-discount
    type2=order.type2

    price2=order.price2
    meters2=order.meters2
    if price2  != None:
        price2=price2*meters2
        return price2
    else:
        price2=None
    discount2=order.discount2
    if discount2 != None:

        total2=price2-discount2
        return total2
    else:
        discount2=None
        total2=None
    # print()
    template=get_template('bill/b.html')
    data={
        'order': order,'total':total,'type':type,'price':price,'meters':meters,'discount':discount,'type2':type2,'price2':price2,'discount2':discount2,'total2':total2,'meters2':meters2
    }
    html = render_to_pdf('bill/b.html', data)
    return HttpResponse(html, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Whenever there are two products then the type2 product will return the value to the context and later on can be used in templates but if there is only product then the type2 should return None so that i can ignore this type 2 in my html using django template filter.

full tracebook

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pro/bill/8/pdf/

Django Version: 2.1.4
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bill',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

    File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\billing-master\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
      34.             response = get_response(request)

    File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\billing-master\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__
      93.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

    File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\billing-master\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
      26.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

    Exception Type: AttributeError at /pro/bill/8/pdf/
    Exception Value: 'float' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback

Comment: please have a look and i have just changed the  field for meters from decimal field to flaotFIeld just to check if its working

Answer (score 0):

You're returning things from the view that aren't `HttpResponse` instances.  This is causing errors in the middleware stack because the middleware expects to receive `HttpResponse` instances.

```
if price2  != None:
    price2=price2*meters2
    return price2          # this won't work!
else:
    price2=None
discount2=order.discount2
if discount2 != None:

    total2=price2-discount2
    return total2          # this won't work!
```

If you want to return these values to the browser, wrap them in an HttpResponse, like this:

```
if price2  != None:
    price2=price2*meters2
    return HttpResponse(str(price2), content_type="text/plain")
else:
    price2=None
discount2=order.discount2
if discount2 != None:

    total2=price2-discount2
    return HttpResponse(str(total2), content_type="text/plain")
```

If you don't want to return these values to the browser - perhaps you just want to set the values for use in your template - then remove the return statements.